# Layover - Guangzhou airport

Tags: canada, airports, china, layovers

I'm an Indian citizen, with PR status in Canada, traveling from Canada to India via China.

I have a layover of 15 hours in Guangzhou, Baiyun International airport. Do I need any visa for the layover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to get a visa. [24-Hour Direct Transit](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-transit-24hour.htm) is available to most countries: contrary to the 72- and 144-hour transit visas, which have a set list of eligible countries, China lists countries that are not eligible for 24-hour direct transit. Fortunately for you, India is not in that list. So your layover of 15 hours can be done without a visa. You will be able, if you want, to go check in in a nearby hotel and take a good rest before going back to the airport.

Comment: I am in similar situation. Traveling from US to India via Beijing. 
My US visa is not valid anymore. Is that a problem?